# lsb_release - could not convert string to float: '8.04 LTS'

Tags: pip, lsb-release

Everything that depends on the `lsb_release` command is not working on my computer.

example:

```
pip install numpy
```

> raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(code, cmd, stdout, stderr) subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lsb_release -a' returned non-zero exit status 1

And in fact, `lsb_release -a` generates an error

```
File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 95, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 59, in main
    distinfo = lsb_release.get_distro_information()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py", line 383, in get_distro_information
    distinfo = guess_debian_release()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py", line 281, in guess_debian_release
    get_distro_info(distinfo['ID'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py", line 41, in get_distro_info
    RELEASES_ORDER.sort(key=lambda n: float(n[0]))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py", line 41, in <lambda>
    RELEASES_ORDER.sort(key=lambda n: float(n[0]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '8.04 LTS'
```

I know that in python `'8.04 LTS'` cannot be converted to a `float`, but why is this happening.

I've tried to reinstall both `lsb_release` and `python-pip` but this does not fix the problem.

I'm on `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`.
any help ?

Comment: Maybe something relevant here? [original lsb-release file should be preserved for classic mode](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1650207)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error on one of my VMs, the other 2 and hypervisor were fine. Same release (16.04.3), not a clue what caused it. It's a known bug.

I got some relief [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lsb/+bug/1662357)

Modify the file `/usr/share/pyshared/lsb_release.py` line 41 from:

```
RELEASES_ORDER.sort(key=lambda n: float(n[0]))
```

to:

```
RELEASES_ORDER.sort(key=lambda n: float(n[0].split()[0]))
```

Fixed the problem for me. Complete credit to SHIINA Hideaki (shiina) at Ubuntu bug launchpad. I'm just reposting it here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when I run `lsb_release -a`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 95, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 59, in main
    distinfo = lsb_release.get_distro_information()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py", line 398, in get_distro_information
    distinfo = guess_debian_release()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py", line 288, in guess_debian_release
    get_distro_info(distinfo['ID'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py", line 48, in get_distro_info
    RELEASES_ORDER.sort(key=lambda n: float(n[0]))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py", line 48, in <lambda>
    RELEASES_ORDER.sort(key=lambda n: float(n[0]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '6.06 LTS'
```

and Let's check the file `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py`

```
try:
    csvfile = open('/usr/share/distro-info/%s.csv' % origin.lower())
except FileNotFoundException:
    # Unknown distro, fallback to Debian
    csvfile = open('/usr/share/distro-info/debian.csv')

....

RELEASES_ORDER = list(RELEASE_CODENAME_LOOKUP.items())
RELEASES_ORDER.sort(key=lambda n: float(n[0]))
```

It loads the file `/usr/share/distro-info/%s.csv`, and convert the first item into float type, which may contants string like 'LTS'. So I modify the line 48 of `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py` as follows, it works for me.

```
RELEASES_ORDER.sort(key=lambda n: (n[0]))
```