# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck on verbose screen on startup

Tags: boot, 18.04

I had done a `sudo apt-get upgrade` and was installing some packages (`truffle`, `nodejs`) when my laptop stopped responding and applications were not opening so I restarted it and when it booted it got stuck in the verbose boot screen and blinking intermittently.

All were showing [OK] so I pressed <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and was able to login but it showed a few python value errors:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '6.06 LTS'
```

How can I fix this and complete the boot sequence please help?

Comment: Also if there is no fix how do I recover my data from the terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After logging into the console look edit this file:

```python
/usr/share/pyshared/lsb_release.py
```

And around line 41 you will see:

```python
RELEASES_ORDER.sort(key=lambda n: float(n[0]))
```

Change it to:

```python
RELEASES_ORDER.sort(key=lambda n: float(n[0].split()[0]))
```

Source: [lsb_release - could not convert string to float: '8.04 LTS'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930837/lsb-release-could-not-convert-string-to-float-8-04-lts)

Comment: I did that but that still doesn't fix the boot issue the screen is still stuck at the verbose page and blinking. Also I noticed that show plymouth boot screen had failed in the verbose page.

Comment: @KousikRajesh But the **string to float** error messages are gone now?

Comment: Yes that is no longer showing

Comment: Would you mind accepting this answer by clicking the check mark next to it and posting a new question with plymouth problems?