# Can I backup all data from a live USB

Tags: boot, package-management, backup, data-recovery, reinstall

My ubuntu 18.04 is broken due to an issue [Ubuntu 18.04 stuck on verbose screen on startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1159476/ubuntu-18-04-stuck-on-verbose-screen-on-startup)

Now I am planning to reinstall ubuntu from USB. I have booted from live USB and was able to backup my home folder by mounting the drive and copying it to an external hard drive.

My question is can I somehow also backup my installed packages and settings from the live USB or can I reinstall ubuntu without overwriting my data or at the very least can I somehow get a list of my installed packages and libraries?

Comment: Well it's worth a shot right? If it's still broken I can always do a fresh install. Is it possible?

Comment: Or is there at least some file where I can find a list of my installed packages so it would be easy for me to reinstall them?

Comment: My daily backup script contains this: `dpkg --get-selections > .packages       # List of installed applications` It's a common technique you can search on. If no one answers I will in a couple/few hours. Going out now...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to backup settings and list of installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/) and [How to list all installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages)